# How to sort date when using excel-bootstrap-table-filter jQuery pluggin

Tags: jquery

I am using [excel-bootstrap-table-filter](https://github.com/chestercharles/excel-bootstrap-table-filter) jQuery pluggin to sort tables on my website. It works like a dream except when it comes to sorting date fields. I have the dates in `DD MMM YYYY` format.

excel-bootstrap-table-filter is sorting the table based on the `DD` value. Anyone knows how to get the plugin to sort dates correctly?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using this [plugin](https://github.com/chestercharles/excel-bootstrap-table-filter) so there no implementation of `date` filter. you need to replace `FilterCollection.prototype.sort` function with below code

```
FilterCollection.prototype.sort = function(column, order, table, options) {
    var flip = 1;
    if (order === options.captions.z_to_a.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')) flip = -1;
    var tbody = $(table).find('tbody').get(0);
    var rows = $(tbody).find('tr').get();
    var th = $(table).find('th')[column];
    var isType = th.getAttribute('istype');
    var dateformat = th.getAttribute('dateformat');
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var A = a.children[column].innerText.toUpperCase();
        var B = b.children[column].innerText.toUpperCase();
        if (isType == 'date') {
            A = moment(A, dateformat);
            B = moment(B, dateformat);
            return A.diff(B, 'd') * flip;
        } else if (!isNaN(Number(A)) && !isNaN(Number(B))) {
            if (Number(A) < Number(B)) return -1 * flip;
            if (Number(A) > Number(B)) return 1 * flip;
        } else {
            if (A < B) return -1 * flip;
            if (A > B) return 1 * flip;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        tbody.appendChild(rows[i]);
    }
};
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gdl)**, I have created a demo using same plugin and I have modify the sort method with I have mentioned above code. Here I have used [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js). I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**Table Code**

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-intel">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filter">Animal</th>
            <th class="filter">Class</th>
            <th class="filter">Collective Noun</th>
            <th dateformat="DD MM YYYY" isType="date" class="filter">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bear</td>
            <td>Mammal</td>
            <td>Sleuth</td>
            <td>11 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ant</td>
            <td>Insect</td>
            <td>Army</td>
            <td>11 05 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Salamander</td>
            <td>Amphibian</td>
            <td>Congress</td>
            <td>11 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Owl</td>
            <td>Bird</td>
            <td>Parliament</td>
            <td>10 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Frog</td>
            <td>Amphibian</td>
            <td>Army</td>
            <td>1 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shark</td>
            <td>Fish</td>
            <td>Gam</td>
            <td>11 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kookaburra</td>
            <td>Bird</td>
            <td>Cackle</td>
            <td>21 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Crow</td>
            <td>Bird</td>
            <td>Murder</td>
            <td>23 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Elephant</td>
            <td>Mammal</td>
            <td>Herd</td>
            <td>11 03 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Barracude</td>
            <td>Fish</td>
            <td>Grist</td>
            <td>30 04 2018</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Jadhav, that worked fine in that the table sort by date as expected. I did not use the class filter and kept my original class and it still worked. However, the date is not correctly sorted in the dropdown. Would be good to have that sorted correctly too, to make it easier for the user to select date intervals

And also thanks for the lesson in collective animal names.

Comment: @Narendra, can you please add the Date format like excel in the respective Dropdown of Date Column, so that to select the data year wise or month wise or day wise as mentioned in this link. See the images. How to apply the Year, Month and Days format like excel filtering on Date Column. https://github.com/chestercharles/excel-bootstrap-table-filter/issues/43